# Running jUnit tests via ANT, clarification needed

Tags: ant, junit

Suppose you have a `test` directory that contains packages each of which contains jUnit tests.

In this setup, using ANT, how would you "**run all tests**?"

Assuming my jUnit has

```
<target name="test" depends="compileTest">
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no">

        <classpath location="${bin}" />

        <formatter type="plain" />
        <test name="_com.??.project.alltests.MyTests" />

    </junit>
</target>
```

Where, MyTests has

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses( { _ThisTest.class, _ThatTest.class })
public class OCTTests {

}
```

and `_ThisTest` itself contains some tests ..

Is it possible for the purposes of ANT script to avoid this ans simply say "Run all Tests you find in this directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [nested batchtest](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html#nested) element of the junit task.
You will find the following example on the [junit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) documentation page:

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="${build.tests}"/>
    <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
  </classpath>

  <formatter type="plain"/>

  <test name="my.test.TestCase" haltonfailure="no" outfile="result">
    <formatter type="xml"/>
  </test>

  <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.tests}">
    <fileset dir="${src.tests}">
      <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
      <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
    </fileset>
  </batchtest>
</junit>
```